# How to slice a list of strings with space delimiter?

Tags: python, string, list, delimiter

I have a list (original_List) that is made up of multiple strings with space in each element as below. How do I create a separate list of the last string (or only file name excluding everything else) of each element from the original list?

```
Original_List = ['-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   134801 Nov  2 14:27 aa_base-13.txt', 
'-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 58630 Nov  2 14:27 aaa_base-extras.txt', 
'-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   300664 Nov  2 14:27 aaa_base-extras.txt']
Expected output for th new list should be as below:
```

Extracted_list

```
['aa_base-13.txt', 'aaa_base-extras.txt', 'aaa_base-extras.txt']
```

Comment: This is tricky to do correctly if you need to handle file names that contain spaces. However, parsing the output of `ls` is generally discouraged. Can't you use [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead?

Answer (score 5):

That's how:

```
new_list = [x.split()[-1] for x in Original_List]
```

Please include your attempts in the future when asking questions.

There is no argument passed to `split` as you can see and that means it takes the default which is the space. Then, the newly created sublists are *sliced* and just the last item is taken (that's what the `[-1]` is for). Try removing it to see what it produces.

Of course as most of the times in programming (if not always) there are many ways to do a task. Another for example would be this:

```
new_list = [y for item in [x.split() for x in Original_List] for y in item if '.' in y]
```

With this second one you are looking for substrings that contain dots `'.'`. You could also replace that with `'.txt'`. That's a more solid way to look for filenames or filenames of a specific extension since they are bound to contain at least one dot.

What the two approaches have in common is that they are **list comprehensions**. This is a core concept in python and i would suggest looking at it if you are serious about this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: he beat ya @tomasn4a by 11 seconds =(

Answer (score 2):

You can try list comprehension:

`[x.split()[-1] for x in Original_List]`

Hope this helps!